# how to insert a loop input into my code

Tags: c++

So here is my code

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>

using namespace std;

int main() { 
    int program = 0;
    int score = 0;

    cout << "Enter the number of assignments that were graded. " << endl;
    cin >> program;

    for (int i=1; i <= program; i++)
        cout << "Enter the score for assignment #" << i <<": ";
}
```

Basically I am trying to find a way that would allow the user to input their score along with the `cout << Enter the score for assignment #"`

Basically I would want the compilier to do this (example):

```
Enter the number of assignments that were graded: 3   
Enter the score for assignment #1: 100   
Enter the score for assignment #2: 75   
Enter the score for assignment #3: 82  
(and so, and so on.)
```

I really have no idea how I am suppose to put the input along the same loop that I created.
is there anyone that can help me out. what code can I use that would allow unlimited loops of inputs along the same line as Enter the score for assignment #x: (input)

Comment: Please consult your C++ reference on how to create loops that contain multiple statements.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I was able to track down the problem I was having and I fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

You used incorrect syntax for include directives. Instead of

```
include iostream
include fstream
```

there must be

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
```

The program could look the following way

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>


int main() 
{
    unsigned int program = 0;

    std::cout << "Enter the number of assignments that were graded: ";
    cin >> program;

    std::vector<unsigned int> scores( program );

    for ( unsigned int i = 0; i < program; i++ )
    {
        std::cout << "Enter the score for assignment # " << i + 1 << ':';
        std::cin >> scores[i];
    }

    // ...
```

Instead of type `unsigned int` you can use type `size_t`

Answer (score 0):

> I really have no idea how I am suppose to put the input along the same loop

Put another input inside the for loop:

```
    for (int i=1; i <= program; i++) {
      cout << "Enter the score for assignment # " << i <<": "<< endl;
      int score;
      cin >> score;
      // ...
    }
```

Writing loops or control flow (`if`,`else`) statements like this

```
    for (int i=1; i <= program; i++)
         statement();
```

is dangerous BTW. It's always better to use the braces `{}`.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you need to create a block of code in your `for` loop:

```
vector<int> grades;

for (int i = 0; i < program; ++i )
{
  int temp_grade = 0;
  cout << "Enter the score for assignment #" << i <<": "; cin >> temp_grade;
  grades.push_back( temp_grade );
}
```

When you want to use some of the `vector`s items, you can use either subscripting or iterators.

For printing the grades via `iterator`s:

```
for(vector<int>::iterator it = grades.cbegin(); it != grades.cend(); ++it)
    cout << *it << " ";
```